# Web download manager aware of only new and changed files

Tags: windows, download-manager

I'm looking for a web download manager that can be smart and only overwrite or rename only new or changed size files. A few times a year I need to freshen local copies of several tens to hundreds of gigabytes of files.

To date I've used FileZilla and WinSCP which both have the ability to compare the local file date/time stamp and the file size with the server's copy and only download what is different. A very useful feature which saves hours and hours of time and 100s of GB of bandwidth, for both me and the hosts.

Ftp still works, however the hosts throttle ftp to 4 connections and max combined speed ~1-2MB/s. The same site over http is limited to 8 connections and ~3-4MB/s combined speed. With ftp I need to set the job to run overnight and see how things went in the morning (and possibly redo some). With http I can run let the job run over lunch plus a bit, even when blindly overwriting all instead of just changed files, and respond to mistakes or redo's immediately.

So, is there any way to bulk download only new changed files from an http source?

Windows preferred but I can spin up a Linux VM if that's the best course.

This is in a corporate setting that disallows and enforces a "no torrents" firewall rule set. Too bad, this is a perfect scenario for a non-warez application of peer to peer technology.

A source to test with: http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/geobase/official/nhn_rhn/

[image: FileZilla's overwrite only new and changed size dialog]

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
wget -Nr -A.zip  http://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/geobase/official/nhn_rhn/gdb_en/01
```

Comment: @mattwilkie Hm, fair point.

Comment: I did try wget a few of years ago but ran into issues with it occasionally corrupting archives. As best I recall it had to do with seeing a different (larger) file size and then appending the new content to the old file instead of overwriting the whole thing. I was unwilling to forego using "resume incomplete" download to accommodate this, because we often experienced dropped connections. It might be time to revisit now though.

Comment: Here's the latest (I think) version of my wget attempts. Maybe my problems were due to the wrong mix of command line options(?) https://gist.github.com/maphew/0f2f1b4f3659440bae82

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised that it worked - I'd been frustrated with the recursive option before. I think the key is that the geobase host allows indexing, otherwise you have to know the path to all the files you want.

Comment: Looks like the --continue option will still have problems. You might be out of luck if you can't keep the wget job running while your connection is dropped.